# How to loop multiple ICollection use recursive (Backtracking)

Tags: c#, recursion, backtracking, icollection

Suppose class `Menu` use property `ICollection<Menu> Items { get ; set ; }` . It is representing data field in mongodb . When insert data and show it will have the following structure:

[image]

I want loop from N1 to N1-child1,child2,child3,.... (done).

[Recursive N1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BszbB.png)

How to when N1 and its children are finished. Looping back to N2 , N3 .

Here is my json code according to mongodb structure:

[image]

[image]

I want to get the Id of branches N1 , N2 , N3 equivalent to `Object1` and `Object2` to compare with the passed ID parameter , if it matches , then stop the recursion

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer, but what you're doing is traversing a tree, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as text so that we can copy, paste, and run your code. Images are useless.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Please don't post comments with links like that. Post an answer in C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209155/659190

Comment: @Enigmativity: I LITERALLY didn't have time, so is it better to provide _zero_ information rather than commenting with a link?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Yes, precisely. This site is about providing quality questions and quality answers for future readers. A link isn't a quality answer. It doesn't show up as an answer to the question (making the question appear less answered) and it certainly can't be accepted as an answer. It detracts from the future value of this question. So, yes, it is better to provide zero information than commenting with a link.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I'd argue that it's also about helping the the person who asked the question, and a quick nudge in the right direction rarely hurts. However I'll take your advice on board, and from now on will either post a complete answer or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super simple. This is all you need:

```
public IEnumerable<Menu> Traversal(Menu menu)
{
    yield return menu;
    if (menu.Items != null)
        foreach (var x in menu.Items)
            foreach (var y in Traversal(x))
                yield return y;
}
```

Comment: I want to get the Id of branches N1 , N2 , N3 to compare with the passed ID parameter , if it matches , then stop the recursion.

Comment: @MuonRoi - You just stop iterating the `IEnumerable<Menu>` when you get what you need.